# How to encrypt on Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

On Ethereum, can only handle 256-bit integers at most. Now, let's say we want to store a 1024-bit public key in a chain and perform homomorphic ciphertext operations on it, and update the result as well.
How is this feasible?

Comment: If it's a **public** key, there is no need to encrypt it at all, it's mean to be public and not a secret.

Comment: @Alejandro I'm sorry for the way I wrote that. The public key is only public. The problem is that the key is hard to store for a very long time, and doing the calculations on the contract consumes a lot of gas.

Answer (score 1):

**Homomorphic encryption** is a type of encryption that allows operations to be performed on encrypted data. Imagine a
scenario where the data is sent to a cloud server for processing. The server processes it and returns the output without knowing anything about the data that it has processed.

You can store encrypted  data on blockchain and computations can be performed on that data without the need for decryption. Enigha project does that.

https://www.media.mit.edu/projects/enigma/overview

Enigma (ENG) is a crypto platform that’s trying to solve the problem of privacy on the blockchain by giving access to data storage and privacy while remaining scalable. Enigma aims to extend Ethereum Smart Contracts by introducing secret contracts.

Secret contracts would operate off-chain, meaning the execution of the contract doesn’t occur on the Ethereum blockchain, but rather sorts any related data into pieces, encrypts those pieces, and distributes them redundantly among Enigma nodes.

Secret Contracts are Rust-based smart contracts that compile to WebAssembly.

This [documentation](https://build.scrt.network/dev/secret-contracts.html) will guide you how to create secret contracts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Enigma seems to be the right solution for this case. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to encrypt things on chain, as every call, parameter, state change, it's completely public anyone could decrypt the information